# canvasで作成した図形&テキストをhtml・cssで出力可能？

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

canvasで作成した図形やテキストを、html・cssで出力(書き出し)する事って可能でしょうか？
参考になるサイトを共有して頂く形でも構いません。方法ありますでしょうか？

Comment: 「書き出し」とはどのような結果を求めているのでしょうか？ 「書き出し」た結果をどう扱うことを想定していますか？

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるのでは？ imageにする [HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL), [How do I export a HTML canvas to an image that can be downloaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61447399/9014308) SVGにする [Get SVG from canvas element and save it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10273516/9014308), [Method to convert HTML5 canvas to SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571294/method-to-convert-html5-canvas-to-svg)